# Pull post image in rails display in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

i've created a JS grid and i'm trying to pull the logo image and display in div data-thumbnail

How do i add the link to pull post images?

```
<%- model_class = Post -%>

<div class="spacer spacer-big"></div>
  <div class="container" style="padding-right:50px;padding-left:50px;">
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="box">
        <div data-thumbnail= "TRYING TO GET POST LOGO HERE" </div>
```

I inserted this `<%=image_tag post.logoimage.url %>` between the quotation marks but i'm still getting an error.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: and what is that  - `<%- model_class = Post -%>`

Comment: undefined local variable or method `post' 

<div data-thumbnail <%=image_tag post.logoimage.url%> </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix**

You'll need to do this:

```
<%= content_tag :div, "", data: { thumbnail: @post.logoimage.url } %>
```

Here's info on [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) for you

This should be accompanied with the following controller action:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def action
       @post = Post.first #-> sets the post object
   end
end
```

--

**Data**

The error you receive is as follows:

> undefined local variable or method `post'

This means your view is calling a non-existent object (variable) (`post`). The solution to this is to make sure that `post` is set correctly. And to do this, you need to either use the `controller` (as per Rails' [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), or set it in the view:

```
<% post = Post.first %>
<%= content_tag :div, "", data: { thumbnail: @post.logoimage.url } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<%- model_class = Post -%>` defines `model_class` as a class, not an object of a class. It should be like `<%- model_class = Post.first -%>` to get an object.

So you should define your post, that you probably meant by first line. It should be:

```
 <% post = Post.first %>
```

then you can use this post:

```
 <%=image_tag post.logoimage.url%>
```

So it is already a tag. You can wrap it in any other.

Comment: Thanks for that, but more so wondering, how do i enter this tag into that div? <%=image_tag post.logoimage.url %>

Comment: Oh, of course it will be `<div><%=image_tag post.logoimage.url%></div>`